# Multiple function calls when linking to a static library

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

In my c++ project I make several calls to a function in a static library, so I wonder if the linker copies that function just once, or everytime it's called in the source code .

Comment: it copy just once, unless it is `inline` function.

Comment: @SHR How exactly will a method that's been inlined into a static library build have an entry point exposed for him to link against?

Comment: @SHR so does it mean it's  copied as an inner function of the executable then all the resolved symbols are forwarded to it ?

Comment: @SHR inline is not guaranteed; and in the case of library functions it has no effect, the generated function call is still a jump to subroutine

Comment: I meant that `inline` can be declared in the header, even if its lib header. if you state inline function and it is short function, then it is almost always be duplicated.

Comment: @alfahim inline function not copied as function, the function code (more or less) been copied where your code call the function. it is done by the compiler, not the linker. other functions from static lib, are copied to your executable once, and it is done by the linker. the answer you've got is not correct, maybe it referring to DLL or shared libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linker copy each used function once.

To make short answer long I'll explain:

when linking with DLL or shared library, there is no copy, your program must load the linked library or DLL into memory if it not already loaded, and call the function from it, static lib are different since there is no dependency at run-time, so every used function is copied to the executable.

There is one exception, `inline` function may be copied for each use, but not copied as function but as code. the function code (more or less) been copied where your code call the function. it is done by the compiler, not by the linker.

`inline` function is guaranteed, it is like a recommendation to the compiler. when you state function as inline you usually put the code in the header file. the compiler may as well decide a function be `inline` even if not stated, as an optimization, and it may occurs where the function is very short.

so the conclusion where linking with a static lib, the function been copied only once to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

The linker does not copy anything. When the compiler finds a function call it does not know the definition for, it leaves it as an external symbol. An the linker will solve the external symbols or throw a linker error.

So, every call to your library methods in your code will translate to a `jump to subroutine` which is an address in the code section.
In the generated binary, this subroutine only exists once.

Hope this sheds a bit more light on the subject.

Comment: I am talking about the final phase when constructing the executable , so the code must be copied from the static library, my concern though is , is it done once or multiple times.

Comment: no, it is copied once, and called using the jmp/ret mechanism

Comment: there is different aspect: static vs dynamic linking, in which case the whole library might get copied in memory multiple times but that has to do with how many processes use the library. It's totally different to what you are asking here